# 噓憑き: what is it and how is it different from 嘘つき?

Tags: kanji, nuances, slang, spelling

While looking at song lyrics I found the word 噓｛うそ｝憑｛つ｝き  . What kind of kanji usage is this, and how does it differ from 噓｛うそ｝つき?

Since 憑 means "haunt, possess" and the song is about ghosts I assumed it was just a pun/irregular variant writing of 噓｛うそ｝つき with the same meaning. Am I correct? Is the meaning slightly different?

I couldn't find it in my usual dictionaries, it's not in the list of [alternate spellings](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%98%98%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8D), and yet there seems to be many results when I search for the term on google. Mostly songs, manga, books, etc. Where does it come from, is it common? Is is some kind of slang? What should I do when I encounter an unconventional word like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you guessed, it is an irregular application of 憑き. One of the few words that are actually used with -憑き is [狐憑き](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E7%8B%90%E4%BB%98%E3%81%8D/#jn-52989), meaning *someone/state of being possessed by a ghost of fox*. So by analogy with this, 嘘憑き may mean *someone haunted by lies*; or possibly *someone addicted to lying* (interpreting 嘘 in 噓憑き as *to lie* rather than a lie itself).